# Bootstrap affix navbar only works on refresh

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, affix

I'm trying to create a website for a friend of mine (for learning purposes also). And now I'm trying to create a affix navbar with Bootstrap. (BTW I'm coding on cloud9 using ruby on rails).

If I preview my site, the affix navbar works perfectly fine, but after clicking on a certain link in the navbar, the navbar just stays on his position below the banner. Through inspecting the element, I found out that the affix classes don't get appended to the navbar anymore, after clicking one of the links. I've spent some hours trying and fixing but nothing seems to work.

So I really hope that one of you guys can help me out.
Thanks in advance.

The code for my application.html.erb is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>NL-Renovatie</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="nav" data-offset="50">

<div class="container-fluid header">
  <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
  <h3>Fixed (sticky) navbar on scroll</h3>
  <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix".</p>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' do %>
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Home
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li id='navbar-button'>
          <%= link_to overons_path do %>
            <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Over Ons
          <% end %>
        </li>
        <li id='navbar-button'>
          <%= link_to new_contact_path do %>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Contact
          <% end %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The code for my application.css.scss is :

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";

.affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.affix + .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
}

.header {
    background-color:#F44336;
    color:#fff;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: may be it because of turbolinks

Comment: @Vishal You're absolutely right, de-activating turbolinks was the answer!

Comment: Than give me thumbs up ;)

Comment: @Vishal How to do that mate? Then I will do it immediatly.

Comment: there is one icon left side of comment. just hover it.. and u see the flag and upvote.. give upvote to my comment..

Comment: There isn't, maybe because I'm new to stackoverflow...

Comment: i give thumb up ur comment check it..

Comment: Yeah I understand the concept mate, but I'm telling you, on my screen there isn't.

Comment: may be you dont have enough reputation. thats why. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by turbolinks. The fix was as following:

In the application.js file I had to remove the following line:

```
//= require turbolinks
```

And in the application.html.erb I've set both data-turbolinks-track to false:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
```

Comment: Is there any solution to this other than disabling Turbolinks?